# What is the PromQL for MAU (Monthly Active Users)?

Tags: prometheus, promql

What is the PromQL query to calculate the monthly active users (MAU) based on the `user` dimension/label in the latency Histogram metric `ServiceLevelIndicator_milliseconds_count`?

I want to create a graph that shows the number of unique users over time.

Is there a PromQL equivalent to the SQL query `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user) FROM ServiceLevelIndicator_milliseconds_count WHERE time BETWEEN @from AND @to`?

Answer (score 1):

That is going to be a very slow query and I encourage you to add a new metric to more directly track this information. That said, here's my best attempt at it:

```
count(group(present_over_time(ServiceLevelIndicator_milliseconds_count[30d])) by (user))
```

Breaking it down to explain the parts:

- `present_over_time(ServiceLevelIndicator_milliseconds_count[30d])` -> takes the last 30 days of data and converts from a range vector to an instant vector (discarding the timestamps and metric values, preserving the labels)
- `group(...) by (user)` -> groups by user so now you have one element per user, all with a value of 1
- `count(...)` -> counts the number of elements in the vector (ie the number of users). You could also use `sum` here instead of `count`, since all of the values are 1, it would give the same result. I don't know if there's a performance difference.

Comment: Thank you. That works.
I tried these samples but failed. 
https://devcodef1.com/news/1016393/getting-unique-labels-in-loki-grafana-query

Comment: The number of users does not seem to go down over time. I can get it to increase but when the traffic stops, the number of users remains the same.
count(group(present_over_time(ServiceLevelIndicator_milliseconds_count[5m])) by (User))